# Include assemblyBinding app.config additions in NuGet package

Tags: c#, nuget, .net-4.7.2

I'm trying to create a NuGet package from a WPF .Net Framework app and having trouble including the `app.config` file. I have this in my csproj file:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <None Update="App.config" Pack="true">
    <PackagePath>lib\net472\$(PackageId).exe.config</PackagePath>
  </None>
</ItemGroup>
```

Everything was working until I added a dependency (Microsoft.Extensions.Logging, I think), which inserts `assemblyBinding` tags into `app.config` before it is written out to `[appName].exe.config` in the bin folder. In the NuGet package I get the original `app.config` file, before the `assemblyBinding` items have been added. Is there something I can add to my csproj file to direct NuGet to include a file directly from the bin folder? (As I understand it, the above snippet tells it to copy from the source files, which never gets the `assemblyBinding` elements.)

Why this is necessary: I have a .Net Framework WPF app that I'm distributing using Squirrel. For Squirrel's use I need to create a NuGet package from my app.